# What 3-day smoke forecasts are height-resolved?

Tags: temperature, weather-forecasting, wildfire

In order to accurately perform weather forecasts during large wildfire events, weather models must include the smoke.  Smoke reflects sunlight back to space, decreasing the light absorbed by the surface of the Earth.  If the smoke is not considered in weather models, temperature can be greatly overestimated.

Some models, such as WRF-Chem, do a fine job of taking care of this problem if good predictions of smoke are available.  However, WRF-Chem is too computationally expensive to be used as an operational weather forecast model.  WRF (without Chemistry) is able to include smoke information.  However, I cannot find any height-resolved smoke forecasts that go out far enough in time (e.g. 72 hours) so that they can be used in a weather forecast framework.  I've considered [BlueSky](https://www.airfire.org/data/bluesky-daily/), but only surface-smoke is given.  I've also considered [FireWork](https://weather.gc.ca/firework/index_e.html), but those forecasts only go out 48 hours. Are there smoke forecasts that are height-resolved and go out at least 72 hours?